# How to ADD to an existing Wordpress query? and NOT replace current/reset current?

Tags: php, wordpress

We currently have a very complicated wordpress(php) script that builds a wp_query call that pulls posts within any taxonomy page that's being viewed. Well I'm trying to add pagination to that query so I need to add the following code:

```
'posts_per_page'=>12, 'paged' => $paged
```

but if I add the following right before my loop:

```
query_posts(array('posts_per_page'=>12, 'paged' => $paged));
```

The entire query just resets to pulling the latest posts and completely ignores the first query. I'm trying to add the above code without disrupting what is already being queried.

Is this possible?

Here's another example:

I'm currently already querying the following:

```
query_posts( array('post_type'=>'videos') ); //the query I don't want to disrupt;
query_posts( array('posts_per_page'=>12, 'paged' => $paged) ); //additions I would like to make to the first query but in a separate part of the file/after the fact.
```

I basically want to combine the 2. In my unique case, I can't simply modify my first query. I need to find a way to add to my 1st query through a second query.

Comment: sorry, but your question is very vague. Are you sure you get the correct `$paged` value? (`$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;`)

Answer (score 0):

You can merge query arguments to the existing query.

```
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array( 'posts_per_page' => '12', 'paged' => $paged  ) );
query_posts( $args );
```

Or you can add to the query

```
global $query_string;
query_posts( $query_string . '&posts_per_page=12' );
```

ect. You can read more about it under "Preserve Existing Queries" on WP Codex. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts